# Форматирование строки с номером телефона C++

Tags: c++, строки, substring

запутался и ничего не понял.
Нужно из строки
"+79995553311"
Сделать строку
"+7(999)555-3311"

Запутался в индексах substr();

```
void Worker::formatting_numberPhone() {
    formatted_numberPhone = "(" + number_phone.substr(0, 3) + ")"
        + number_phone.substr(3, 3) + "-" + number_phone.substr(6, 4);
}

void Worker::getData() {
    formatting_numberPhone();
    std::cout << name << ' ' << subname <<
        "\nNumber phone: " << formatted_numberPhone << "\nCompany: " << company << "\nid: " << id;
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А если строка +380665553322? Когда дают только правило, без примера — плохо, но пример без правила — еще хуже... Да и пример — отрывок из обрывка, что за типы и члены, остается только догадываться.

Comment: Пока что хочу сделать форматирование для номера с +7, а дальше уже буду думать как реализовать форматтер номеров для остальных стран)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то Вы странное написали с индексам, поэтому давайте попробуем заново составить форматирование. Разберем Ваш номер:

+79995553311

Вы хотите получить из него строку

+7(999)555-3311

Смотрим. Перед скобкой должны оставаться два первых символа. Параметры `substr` имеют следующий смысл: первый - индекс начала подстроки, второй - количество символов в подстроке. Индексы начинаются с нуля. Тогда первые два символа мы получим так:

```
number_phone.substr(0, 2)
```

В скобках стоят три символа, начиная с индекса 2 (помним, что индекс первого элемента - 0). Значит нам нужно следующее:

```
number_phone.substr(2, 3)
```

После скобок до дефиса стоит три символа. Получаем их:

```
number_phone.substr(5, 3)
```

После дефиса стоит оставшаяся часть строки, начиная с 9 символа. Поэтому так:

```
number_phone.substr(8, 20)
```

Почему 20? Чтобы получить весь остаток строки, независимо от длинны номера. Как это работает, оставлю Вам для самостоятельного разбора.

В итоге получим следующую строку:

```
    formatted_numberPhone = number_phone.substr(0, 2) + "(" 
        + number_phone.substr(2, 3) + ")" + number_phone.substr(5, 3) +  "-" +number_phone.substr(8, 20);
```

Comment: А если это реализовать с помощью std::format(), то как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Не работал с ```std::format()```, нужды не было.  Если правильно понимаю, строка формата должна выглядеть так: ```"{}({}){}-{}"```, но Вам нужно все равно разбирать строку на подстроки, чтобы передать их функции. Но допускаю, что тут я не прав.

Comment: Я бы работал с конца... 7 цифр номера, три - код, а уж потом страна. Потому и написал комментарий с вопросом о правилах разбора...

Comment: @Harry Вы правы, как и @megorit в своем ответе. Но я не стал особо задумываться о структуре номеров, сосредоточившись на том,  чтобы донести, как определять параметры для ``substr```

Answer (score 2):

Тут нужно начинать с конца, поскольку код страны может быть двузначным, а может и трёхзначным, и плюса там может не быть.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
    

std::string format_phone(const std::string& phone) {
    // Минимальный размер номера. Например: 89995553311
    if (phone.size() < 11)
        throw std::length_error{"Invalid phone length"};

    return std::string{phone.begin(),phone.end()-10}
         + "(" + std::string{phone.end()-10,phone.end()-7} + ")"
         + std::string{phone.end()-7,phone.end()-4} + "-"
         + std::string{phone.end()-4,phone.end()};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << format_phone("+79995553311") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

А вообще, самым эффективным спосбом будет сначала зарезервировать `phone.reserve(phone.size()+4)` и затем через `insert` добавлять разделители.